# Application crashes in background when changing camera access from settings

Tags: ios

When I change camera access from settings, from not accessed to accessed or vise versa my application crashed with external accessory problem (it is in background) **/SourceCache/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-288.20.7/EAAccessoryManager.m:__51-[EAAccessoryManager _checkForConnectedAccessories]_block_invoke-631 ending background task**

Comment: Check this answer, maybe helps you

http://stackoverflow.com/a/30468600/6124910

Comment: Thank you I thought it is crash.